# How do i compare two text files in c++

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

**okay I've searched everywhere and couldn't get my hand on it so ..**

1. i'm doing a library system where a librarian enters his username and the program checks if he is one of the librarians or not
2. i'm stuck on the comparing part , i tried using getline but it gave me an error , tried gets_s and used a char array instead of a string and still didn't work

kindly help me with what i should do

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    //opening files
    ifstream readUsername;
    ofstream enterUsername;
    //variables
    string existUsername;
    string enteredUsername;
    //reading files
    readUsername.open("librarian usernames.txt");
    if (readUsername.fail())
    {
        cout << "can't open file" << endl;
    }
    enterUsername.open("entered librarian username.txt");
    if (enterUsername.fail())
    {
        cout << "can't open file" << endl;
    }
    while(!readUsername.eof)
    {       
        readUsername >> existUsername;
    }
    enterUsername << enteredUsername;

    readUsername.close();
    enterUsername.close();
    enterUsername.clear();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `while(!readUsername.eof)` should not compile. It should be `while(!readUsername.eof())` - but note that it's the wrong way to do that check since the `eof` bit won't be set until _after_ you've tried to read beyond EOF. Do: `while(readUsername >> existUsername) { ... }` instead.

Comment: The loop will, as it's currently written, read all strings in the file and then put the last string in the `enterUsername` stream. No comparison is done.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile;
infile.open("listOfWords.txt"); //open file

for(string listOfWords; getline(infile, listOfWords, '.'); ) //read sentences including
//spaces

cout<<listOfWords; //this displays

return 0;
}
```

This shows you how to output the text so you should just save both files to a variable then compare the variables.